# Route with dynamic id is not working in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to create a route with dynamic id as `<Route exact path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} />` and `Profile` is imported correctly. Profile page is not loading and shows an error in the console as

`GET http://localhost:8080/profile/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/profile/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Other Routes without params works fine and also the Profile.jsx page has created without any failure. How can I fix this?

My App.jsx

```
import { Profile } from '../HomePage/Profile';
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const router = (                
            <div className="outer">
                <Route path="/application" component={Application} />
                <Route exact path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} />             
            </div>
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                {router}
            </Router>
        );
   }
}
```

Here the Application router works fine as it doesn't have a second param.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

from the index.html to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not available Hitesh. I just fixed it by adding `publicPath: '/'` inside webpack.config.js